# Can't dispatch action inside middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create jwt middleware

```
export function jwt({ dispatch, getState }) {
  return (next) => (action) => {
      const authReducer = getState().AuthorizationReducer;

      if(authReducer && authReducer.token.accessToken) {
        const {
          refreshToken,
          time,
        } = getState().AuthorizationReducer.token;

        const details = {
          client_id: authReducer.getToken.clientId,
          client_secret: authReducer.getToken.clientSecret,
          grant_type: 'refresh_token',
          refresh_token: refreshToken
        };

        let now = +Moment(Date.now());

        if (now > time) {
          const queryString = Object.keys(details).map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(details[k])}`).join('&');
          return next(getAccessTokenByRefreshToken(queryString));
        }
      }

      return next(action);
  };
}
```

But I never be inside getAccessTokenByRefreshToken. It's looks like:

```
export function getAccessTokenByRefreshToken(queryString) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(refreshTokenStart());
    fetch(`${API_URL}oauth/v2/token?${queryString}`, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        debugger;
        dispatch(refreshTokenComplete(json));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(refreshTokenError(err.error));
        Actions.launch();
      });
  }
}
```

I using redux and aply my middleware inside applyMiddleware function. 
Question is how I can dispatch my action?

Comment: How are you dispatching action, any code regarding that?

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh getAccessTokenByRefreshToken it's function where I dispatch to store

Comment: where and how are you calling `getAccessTokenByRefreshToken` ?

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh first part of my question
return next(getAccessTokenByRefreshToken(queryString));

I register this jwt function as middleware